# disable click if of <A> if div selected has same id

Tags: jquery, class, unbind, disable-link

I have a one page site, and i m sliding divs, the div which is visible has class selected.

E.g if ID ONE has class selected, so link which has href #one shld be disabled.

NOTE: I have multiple LINKS which could point to #one, so want to disable all

```
<div id="one" class="selected">one</div>
<div id="two">one</div>

<a href="#one" id="linkOne">displays two</a>
<a href="#two" id="linkTwo">displays two</a>
```

I know its confusing and i m really sorry abt it!

**EDIT: Can I get ID 'e.g. ONE' of div selected and find all  which has same # 'e.g. #ONE'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add a disabled class to all A tags where their href matches the id of any element which has the selected class:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").removeClass('disabled');
    $('.selected').each(function() {
        $('a[href=#' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('disabled');
    });

// If by 'disabled', you mean you want the link not to work, then add this:

    $('a.disabled').on('click',function(e) {
        alert('you can\'t do that');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Example** here: http://jsfiddle.net/dtxan/4/

Answer (score 0):

In your click-callback you could use the attribute-selector and select all elements with a matching href. A simplfied example, since I don't know what your click-callback looks like:

```
$(".selectorForAllYourLinks").on("click", function () {

    // ### Do what you do to show the div when clicked

    // Remove the disabled class from all anchors
    $("a").removeClass("disabled");

    // Add the disabled class to all anchors referencing the now visible div
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $("a[href='"+id+"']").addClass("disabled");
});
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zS5RS/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$(".selected").each(function() {
    $('a[href="#' + $(this).attr("id") + '"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```